# ASP.NET MVC app is throwing a 403.14

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. The app is using a client-side JavaScript framework. This app works fine when I visit the main URL. That URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:1801/my-app/Item?i=123
```

However, when I load the app in an older browser (IE8), the user gets redirected to a URL with a hash (#) in it. The new URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:1801/#/my-app/Item?i=123
```

In the case of older browsers, ASP.NET MVC returns a status code of 403.14. I've confirmed that the route is the problem. I did so by copying and pasting the second URL into Chrome. In other words, the app works in Chrome with the first URL, however, I get a 403.14 in Chrome with the second URL.

How can I make ASP.NET MVC accept the second URL? From my understanding, the client-side framework is adding the hash as some fallback method because HTML 5 routing isn't supported in IE 8.

Thank you!

Comment: we need a bit more info to decipher what is happening here.  Which client-side framework are we talking about? Where are the URLs being generated (by this client-side framework, or by Razor)?  You probably don't really want MVC to accept the hash URLs; rather, you probably want to troubleshoot why your client framework is trying to use client side (hash) routes for server URLs.  The intent of the hash is to indicate that the route be handled in javascript, not by the server.

Comment: @AndrewCounts - AngualrJS is the client-side framework. THe URLs are just MVC routes. However, for some reason, in IE9, AngularJS does a client-side rerouting and includes the '#'

Comment: still seems to me you need to rewrite this question, and perhaps show some example code of when you are using Angular routes vs when you are using server routes.  This is not an issue with ASP.Net MVC, as it would never generate a `#` nor expect one for a server route.  Either these are indeed Angular routes that are not being handled by Angular, or Angular is incorrectly generating the external links.